# How to remove a user from a channel via sync function

Tags: couchbase-sync-gateway

How is a user removed from a channel when the user was granted access via sync function?

As I understand it adding a document to a channel operates on the document revision. It is therefore easy to remove a document from a channel (or remove a channel from a document? I suppose there is a single right way of phrasing this) as each update of a document sets the document's channel to nil and the sync function can decide further what to do.

Would granting a user access to a channel via access() do the same? I read the following [here](https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway/wiki/Multi-Channel-Replication), which suggests it does:

> When a document is updated and either the previous or the current
>   revision grants channel access, all of the users and roles named in
>   both revisions' access lists have their all_channels properties
>   cleared to nil to invalidate them.

In which case it operates similar to document channel assignment.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the answer from the documentation:

[Sync Function API](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/guides/sync-gateway/sync-function-api-guide/index.html)

> The sync function is called every time a new revision/update is made
>   to a document, and the changes to channels and **access** made by the
>   sync function are tied to that revision. If the document is later
>   updated, the sync function will be called again on the new revision,
>   and the **new channel assignments and user/channel access replace the
>   ones from the first call**.

Emphasis mine.